# iterate through open forms and close particular forms only

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, openform

- given below is the code i wrote

  ```
  Private Sub CloseTransactionForms()
    Dim ActiveFroms As New List(Of String)
    Dim formToClose As New List(Of Form)
    Dim j As Integer
    ActiveFroms.Add("FrmSale")
    ActiveFroms.Add("FrmpPurchase")
    ActiveFroms.Add("FrmSaleReturn")
    ActiveFroms.Add("FrmPurchaseReturn")
      Try
        For Each frm As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
          For j = 0 To ActiveFroms.Count - 1
              If frm.Name.ToString() = ActiveFroms.Item(j) Then
                  formToClose.Add(frm)
              End If
          Next
      Next
      If formToClose.Count > 0 Then
          Dim i As Integer
          For i = 0 To formToClose.Count - 1
              Dim xform As Form = formToClose.Item(i)
              xform.Close()
          Next
      End If
    Catch ex As Exception
   End Try
  End Sub
  ```
- this code will iterate through the open forms in my application and close the *defined forms* from the application
- but it seems not good for me (using 3 for loops in it and it took sometimes while iterating via for loop) i think there will be another good method, please suggest a good solution for me

*Note : i have already seen [this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12940279/3814846)*

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the question you linked, and additionally unclear what you're asking. Why does the code seem "not good for you"? You might be able to filter forms more elegantly using LINQ ([IEnumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb337697(v=vs.100).aspx)), but that doesn't have much to do with closing forms.

Comment: duplicate > not its not because in my case i need to close only 4 forms from the `openfoms` ..............  not good for you > as you can see i have used 3 `for loop` in that code

Comment: You modify the collection that you are iterating.  That always ends up poorly.  You must iterate it backwards from Count-1 to 0 to avoid accidents.

Comment: @Hans: he's actually creating a separate list of forms to close.

Comment: Okay, no idea what "vlose" was supposed to mean :)

Comment: Apparently, it's about vlosing some active froms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to find the forms you want to close and `List.ForEach` to close them:

```
Dim ActiveFroms = New List(Of String) From {"FrmSale", "FrmpPurchase", "FrmpSaleReturn", "FrmPurchaseReturn"}

Dim formsToClose = From form In My.Application.OpenForms.Cast(Of Form)()
                   Join activeFormName In ActiveFroms
                   On form.Name Equals activeFormName
                   Select form

formsToClose.ToList().ForEach(Sub(form) form.Close())
```

You cannot use a `For Each` with the query above because `Form.Close` will modify the collection [which is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604831/collection-was-modified-enumeration-operation-may-not-execute). Therefore i use `List.ForEach`.

Comment: I almost finished writing the same thing so I took the liberty of adding the initializer part to your answer.

Comment: @TimSchmelter does `formsToClose.ToList().ForEach(Sub(form) form.Close())` is correct?? am getting `Expression Expected`  on [sub](http://127.0.0.1)

Comment: Which version of Vb.Net are you using?

Comment: @TimSchmelter `Visual Studio 2008` `(VB 9.0)`

Comment: @keet: then [lambda-expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253(v=vs.90).aspx) are already supported. It works for me, i've tested it. Are you sure that you get the compiler error at `... ForEach(Sub ...`? However, as a workaround you can also use `Dim listOfForms=formsToClose.ToList()`. Then use a simple `For`-loop.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes am sure ...anyways i'll try your suggestion

Comment: @keet: i cannot test it now, but i'll check later if it works also for me if i compile with .NET 3.5 (i've tested it yesterday with VS 2010).